# Escape some HTML tags with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, html-sanitizing

I've just started working with mongoose and I have a use-case where I want to have a whitelist of "safe" HTML tags (ie, `<i>`, `<b>`, `<u>`, others), but I want to remove malicious ones, such as `<script>`. I'm currently trying to find a sanitizing middleware that supports something like this, but so far all I've found is [`validator.js`](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js) and that doesn't seem to support whitelisting HTML, just whitelisting characters.

My use-case is as follows:
I'd like to use [summernote](http://hackerwins.github.io/summernote/) to create some nicely-formatted things that rely on user input, save them to mongodb using mongoose, and then display that particular HTML elsewhere.

Is there some middleware that will help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had great success with [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.org/package/cheerio). It provides a jquery like api so you can select html elements right from node js. You could create a list of tags that you don't want in the final output and [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) them. For instance script tags can be removed like so

```
   var cheerio = require('cheerio');         
   $ = cheerio.load("<html><body><script></script></body></html>");
   $("script").remove();
```

That's it.

Comment: Very cool. I've used cheerio before but I had never thought to use it for this sort of situation. Thank you! Just a question, is there some significance to the `.load("html fragment")`? Does that mean it won't expect a full HTML doc?

Comment: It can accept any valid html string even the full document.